# Add a new section in product edit page

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui, product-edit

I want to add a new section in product edit form with form element(file uploader) for that I created the product_form.xml and added the required fields.to get the input data, I use a catalog_product_save_after observer.issue is data that is input to the form field is not coming in the request.

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="attachment_products" sortOrder="30">
    <settings>
        <collapsible>true</collapsible>
        <label translate="true">Document Attachments</label>
    </settings>

    <field name="attachment_product" sortOrder="110" formElement="fileUploader">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">product</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/uploader/image</elementTmpl>
            <dataType>string</dataType>
            <label translate="true">file Image</label>
            <visible>true</visible>
            <notice translate="true">Maximum file size: 2 MB.  Allowed file types: JPEG, GIF, PNG, JPG, PDF</notice>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <fileUploader>
                <settings>
                    <uploaderConfig>
                        <param xsi:type="url" name="url" path="achmentsadmin/files/upload"/>
                    </uploaderConfig>
                    <allowedExtensions>jpg jpeg gif png pdf</allowedExtensions>
                    <maxFileSize>4194304</maxFileSize>
                </settings>
            </fileUploader>
        </formElements>
    </field></fieldset>
</modal>
```

but when I add the following code after the form tag and wraps the whole fieldset tag, I can get the data from the post request.

```
<modal name="advanced_inventory_modal"></modal>
```

but it adds inside the advance inventory section. I want to add as a separate tab.can you please let me know the issue here
Thanks

Comment: thanks for the answer. but I prefer doing it using the UI component. any idea why it works in a different way as I explained in the above question?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution to add a new section in the product edit section is either using setup script and adding required attributes or using modifiers.I followed this tutorial and found the answer

https://www.mageworx.com/blog/2016/08/an-easy-way-to-add-a-fieldset-with-fields-to-the-ui-form/